# How to get to the requesting type in a Castle Windsor factory method?

Tags: logging, castle-windsor

I would like to use factory method during component registration to integrate static logger factory like this:

```
Component
    .For<ILogger>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, componentModel, creationContext) => LoggingFactory.GetLogger("..."))
    .LifestyleTransient(),
```

`GetLogger` class expects the name of logging context. I would like to pass there full name of the class that requested logger. This would be unambiguous in this case as the lifestyle of ILogger service is transient.

I see that there is `creationContext.RequestedType` (that contains `ILogger`), but no `creationContext.RequestingType`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get resolving type from `creationContext.Handler.ComponentModel.Name`.
The following code should do what you need:

```
Component
   .For<ILogger>()
   .UsingFactoryMethod((kernel, componentModel, creationContext) => LoggingFactory.GetLogger(creationContext.Handler.ComponentModel.Name))
   .LifestyleTransient(),
```

Comment: It's not exactly it as component name sometimes differ from type name even in cases without explicitly setting name during registration -- for example, in interceptors. But still, it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: I am probably going to use ``LoggingFactory.GetLogger(creationContext.Handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.FullName)``.